# how to use cursor.execute to get all elements in a list for a matching criteria using python and psycopg2 only?

Tags: python-3.x, psycopg2

I have a list of email ids in a list. Using cursor.execute, I need to get all email ids matching a particular domain in the postgresql table. How do I achieve this in python 3.8?
Does this give the desired rows from the table.

```
    sql2 = cur.execute('Select * from mailids where domain in %s',(list1,))
    mgrp_list = cur.fetchall()
```

Assume domain is another field in the mailids table

Answer (score 0):

You can use `where domain = any(%s)`.